# guessing game updating <li> elements with user guess using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am starting to explore Jquery and I am working on a simple "guessing game" where the user has to type a number between 1 -100. I have designed 5 boxes to "record" the guesses made so far but I am having trouble updating these boxes one by one. So far, when a user types in his/her guess, the number he/she types updates ALL my *li* elements (boxes). I want it to update the first box with the first guess, the second one with the second guess... how can I accomplish this? should I use *append()* instead of text() ? if so, how can I do it? thanks!

This is my code so far :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newGame = new Game();
  console.log("document ready");
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    makeAguess(newGame);
  });

  $("#player-input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      makeAguess(newGame);
    }
  });
}); 


function makeAguess(game) {
  var input = $("#player-input").val();
  $("#player-input").val("");
  var output = game.playersGuessSubmission(parseInt(input));
  if (output === "You have already guessed that number." && output !== "You Lose.") {
    $("h1").replaceWith("<h1>" + "Please guess again!" + "</h1>");
  } else {
    $("#guesses li").text(function (){   // here is where I am having trouble.
      return input; 
    })
  }
}
```

My current output :

[image: the user entered 34 as his last guess]

Comment: You should supply the appropriate HTML and CSS as well.

Comment: `$("#guesses li")` will in fact returns all li element. but you can use `$("#guesses li:first")` to get the first one. https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: @JasonSperske You can use `$("#guesses li:eq(x)")` where `x` is the index of the `li` you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

**One:** Keep track of the number of guesses the user has done so far. We'll call this `guesses` and starts at 0. But you'll need to make sure `guesses` never exceeds the amount of attempts (the number of `li`s) they have minus 1 as arrays start at 0. Maybe doing a check for:

`if ( guesses < max_guesses ) { // let's play }`

**Two:** Use jQuery's `eq` method on an array of selected objects to target the specific one.

`$("#guesses li").eq(guesses).text(input)`

And all together we have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newGame = new Game();
  var guesses = 0;
  console.log("document ready");
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    makeAguess(newGame, guesses);
    guesses++;
  });

  $("#player-input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      makeAguess(newGame, guesses);
      guesses++;
    }
  });
}); 


function makeAguess(game, guesses) {
  var input = $("#player-input").val();
  $("#player-input").val("");
  var output = game.playersGuessSubmission(parseInt(input));
  if (output === "You have already guessed that number." && output !== "You Lose.") {
    $("h1").replaceWith("<h1>" + "Please guess again!" + "</h1>");
  } else {
    $("#guesses li").eq(guesses).text(input)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> So far, when a user types in his/her guess, the number he/she types updates ALL my li elements (boxes)

- In order to update a box corresponding to the guess, you need to make the box unique.
- Also, you need to keep track of how many tries the user has already taken

You can combine the above two points and come up with an approach, as shown below--

```js
var totalGuesses = 0;

jQuery("#submitGuess").on("click", function(e) {
    if(totalGuesses < 5) {
     totalGuesses++;
        var userGuessed = jQuery("#userGuess").val();
        jQuery("#guess"+totalGuesses).html(userGuessed);
    } else {
     jQuery("#noMoreGuesses").html("Max Guesses Reached!");
    }
});
```

```css
#userGuessLog {
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
}

.ugVal {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userGuessLog">
    <div id="guess1" class="ugVal">
    </div>
    <div id="guess2" class="ugVal">
    </div>
    <div id="guess3" class="ugVal">
    </div>
    <div id="guess4" class="ugVal">
    </div>
    <div id="guess5" class="ugVal">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="noMoreGuesses">
</div>

<input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submitGuess" id="submitGuess" value="Submit Guess" />
```

I have created a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vktrd1p/) to demonstrate this.

Comment: Nice! this is a nice approach! thanks for enlightened me!